# Triangle Pattern Background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, patterns

I'm using Adobe Photoshop CC. I have a background that I want to convert it into a triangle shaped pattern for example, check the tiles on this picture [image]

I have found a tutorial on how to do it but did not get it right, see this [image]

This is what I've made, as you can see.. pattern is not clear. How do I make the pattern clear like in the first picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a background:

[image]

2. Duplicate twice and rasterize if necessary
3. On top layer, Transform Horizontal Skew 45° (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Then Filter > Pixelate > Mosaic. Then Transform Horizontal Skew -45° effectively putting it back in original position.
4. On middle layer same thing but do -45° then Mosaic then +45°
5. Lower opacity of both layers to 50% and then move them to a position you like:

[image]

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I did. but is there a way I can make the patterns more noticeable? just like in the first image.

Comment: Well that's not really what you asked, you asked how to make it clear. Yours looks fuzzy and misaligned so didn't even know how you created it. As far as more noticeable -- can use actual vector triangles. Could probably also follow the same steps but with different colors. The ones that aren't "clear" is because the colors are very similar. Adding more layers with different colors would be a solution. @ElShaikhaShaikha

Comment: Adding to Ryan's comment, your triangles are also too big (or your background too small / not enough variation). Try with smaller triangles on randomly distributed colors (you can use the brush to paint it) and they will become more noticeable.