# What program is used to make a triangular mesh illustration?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

What program did this designer used to make this image? and the dot link effect? and if there is any tutorial?

[image]

Comment: Big tutorial at this link http://vectorboom.com/load/tutorials/effects/polygonal_vector_mosaic/3-1-0-305

Answer (score 0):

The image is a 2D projection of a 3D triangle mesh model of a microscope. There are some image effects and edits added in 2D:

- glow
- node markers at line ends, also loose small dots inserted here and there
- some triangles are ripped apart and some have got half transparent fill
- local brightness variations, manual or generated by the cumulative effect of many partially transparent objects at the same place

We can test this theory with a simple object (my low cost software and hardware really cannot handle complex models reasonably fast)

Here is a simple 3D piece in a freeware CAD (=DesignSpark Mechanical). In the right there's the same piece after converting it to an OBJ file, which are triangle meshes:

[image]

DS Mechanical cannot save the triangle mesh as 2D vector image, but fortunately there's other software which can read the OBJ file and make the conversion. I have under testing Shade3D, which can do it. The OBJ file was opened and saved as Adobe Illustrator AI file. Illustrator opened it:

[image]

It's a big bunch of separate triangles. Typically every visible line contains a side from two triangles. If some triangles are wanted to be ripped apart or filled with a color, it's possible, every triangle is selectable and movable.

Nodes in your example contain circular markers. We can add them as arrowheads in the Strokes panel. We put them only in the beginnings of the paths, because our paths are closed. We change at the same time black color to blue.

[image]

Dark background and effect Stylize > Outer Glow will make the result a little more plausible. Glow color is blueish, but not the same as the stroke color, it must seem brighter:

[image]

The glow is actually an inserted Gaussian blur. It's intensified in places where many pieces overlap. We can use the same to make some bright white spots.

We make into new top layer a copy of our shape. It has white stroke color , white outer glow and reduced opacity. The total effect is this:

[image]

NOTE: the cumulative brightening does not happen if the shape is grouped before applying the effects and opacity reduction, because a group is handled as one. We must have 2 layers to keep the differently colored parts separate.

Looking more closely your example shows that the bright white spots are not all in places where many lines meet. Thus we have a good reason to believe that they are inserted manually, which gives much more freedom and simplifies the image radically.

**If you can accept working with bitmaps**, you can open the OBJ file in Photoshop. (=insert the model as a new rendered layer to an existing Photoshop image). Wireframe rendering and node markers come out easily:

[image]

Having a couple of differently effected and adjusted versions + adding some white spots manually make a plausible result:

[image]

There's still needed much tweaking before you get the same appearance as your example, but hopefully this is a good start. If Photoshop is acceptable final working environment, the answer to the question is "Any 3D program which outputs the model as OBJ file".

Just tried the receipe to a low polygon count real 3D model, too. Only few decorative elements were added. Photoshop seemingly accepts at least this simple 3D model with no hiccups. Working the same in Illustrator was clearly more sluggish.

[image]

**This reveals clearly the weakness:** Entry level 3D CAD programs are not good choices for basic triangulation. They try to make as simple and as regular triangle composition as possible keeping the given tolerances. This is engineering, arty looks need triangles that have more random positions and somehow limited side length ratios. If one wants to createthe triangles in 3D, he must use software that allows more control over the triangulation.